# apply bouncing effect & rotation on moving image along x-axis android studio

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Animation_Layout animation_layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        animation_layout = new Animation_Layout(this);
        setContentView(animation_layout); // create our own graphic layout, instead of layout.xml
    }
}

public class Animation_Layout extends View {

    Bitmap tumbleweed_V, shadow_tumbleweed;
    float pos_x, pos_y = 320;
    float x_dir = 2;

    public Animation_Layout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check_background);

    }

    @Override // Built in function to draw whatever u want on ur canvas
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        tumbleweed_V = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tumbleweed);
        shadow_tumbleweed = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shadow_tumbleweed);
        // for motion on both images
        if (pos_x >= canvas.getWidth()) {
            pos_x = 120;
        }


        pos_x = pos_x + x_dir;



        canvas.drawBitmap(tumbleweed_V, pos_x, pos_y, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(shadow_tumbleweed, pos_x, pos_y + 80, null);
        invalidate(); // clear function and call again & again onDraw() func

    }
}
```

The image `tumbleweed` & `shadow_tumbleweed` perfectly move along x-axis and start again from initial position after colliding canvas walls but I am unable to put bounce effect & rotation on that moving images along x-axis.I tried a lot of ways but unfortunately didn't succeed.please help me  out and also provide functionality how these effect working because I am new on animations.

Comment: Fix your code blocks when you get a chance.  Not all of your code is wrapped up inside of the code blocks.

Comment: _I tried a lot of ways but unfortunately didn't succeed_ - Please edit your post to describe what you have tried so far and the problems you have encountered with that.

Comment: means to move image along x-axis, and want to apply bounce effect on it as well.@zett42

Comment: Succeeded in apply bounce effect along y-axis but unfortunately image not move along x-axis@zett42